# executing VBScript within R

Tags: r, vbscript

I have simple VBScript

```
Dim VObj As Object
.
.
.
End With
```

Currently I am executing this script within R by first saving this script locally on my computer as `test.vbs` and then calling this script using

```
shell(shQuote(normalizePath(....../test.vbs), "cscript", flag = "//nologo")
```

I am trying to avoid saving the script as a vbs file locally and then calling this using `shell(shQuote(`. I want to execute this vb script directly within R starting from `Dim VObj........End With`. Any pointers on how to accomplish this is much appreciated.

Comment: Short of implementing a VBScript interpreter in R, I don't see how this would be possible. If the script is simple enough, why not just throw it away and rewrite it in R?

Comment: @JohnColeman I am assuming you are not familiar with R :)

Comment: I know that R doesn't always make things easy (which is why Python is making some inroads into R's traditional domain) but in your case either translating to R or living with what you are currently doing seem to be the only viable options. If you decide to go the translation route, you could post a follow-up question about any issues that you encounter.

Comment: Would you also object to creating the VBS file within R (e.g. using 'writeLines(text = script_lines, con = "New Script.vbs")` and then using system() or shell() on the new script? Because unless you build a VBScript interpreter in R, as @JohnColeman mentioned, that seems like the best you can do.